# Align two columns(div) each under other when page width is low

Tags: html, css

here is my  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QV26k/3/) `code`
if you change horizontal size up, divs(section 1 and 2) are horizontaly centered. But if width is low, section 2 goes under section 1. Problem is how to center them? I tried many posibilities with wrappers, but no result. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I think I see what you mean. Well, since you have fixed widths for `#section_first` and `#section_second`, I think this can still be done with (mostly) media queries. Before giving the fix though, a couple of things need to be changed:

First, remove `display:inline-block` from your definition of `#main`, since otherwise it'll be problematic to center the children of `#main` later. Additionally, remove `display:inline` from both `#section_first` and `#section_second`, since that style is completely overridden by the floats you apply to them, and they'll only cause problems later.

Now, rearranging your HTML a bit so that `#clearer` allows `#main` to scale to the size of its contents (basically, moving `#clearer` inside `#main`):

```
<div id="page_content">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="section_first">Section 1</div>
        <div id="section_second">Section 2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="clearer"></div>
</div>
```

At this point, nothing should really have changed in the layout - so now let's add some responsiveness with media queries:

```
@media (max-width:478px) {
    div#section_first {
        margin:0 auto;
        float:none;
    }
    div#section_second {
        margin:0 auto;
        float:none;
    }
}
```

The max-width of 478px was calculated since `#main` has a width of 90%, and the combined width of its contents is 200px + 200px + 30px (margin) = 430px. And 430px / 0.9 = 477.777px, which we can round up to 478px so that the alternate styles kick in before you get unwanted display issues. The styles within the media query stop the floating of the children, and center them with the common `margin:0 auto`.

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QV26k/9/) demonstrating the modified code. Note that I also removed the default margin on `<html>` and `<body>` using CSS. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thank you very much :-) You're god :-) some new informations for me about float and display.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0) is what you're looking for.

They let you define CSS styles conditionally depending on - for example - window width.

```
@media (min-width:450px) {
    //some CSS to center the div.
}
```

Comment: I am using media queries. But my code here is example for mobile. On mobile is allowed that second div goes under first. Only what I need is center them in #main

Comment: So where is the problem? "if width < X, then center divs"

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to do this.

`@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) { //Css here }`
You need to find out when it seems to be breaking, and then change the max-width to that. And in your media query css, instead of using px use %.

But you also need to have a width on your main div. `width:100%;`

Here is a DEMO and the code below:

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/QV26k/18/

```
* {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
}
body {
    background-color: darkgreen;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
div#page_content {
    background-color: darkblue;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 430px;
    min-width: 220px;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
div#main {
    background-color: pink;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width:100%;
}
div#section_first {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
div#section_second {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px
}
div#clearer {
    clear:both;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {

div#section_first {
    width: 46%;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
}
div#section_second {
    width: 46%;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-left: 2%;
}
}
```